# How to flatten a dataframe within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to flatten a dataframe that is inside the dataframe. In this example, the column `account` has a dataframe as value. I would like to flatten this into a single dataframe.

Example: **(Updated)**

```
import panda as pd
account1 = pd.DataFrame([{'nr': '123', 'balance': 56}, {'nr': '230', 'balance': 55}])
account2 = pd.DataFrame([{'nr': '456', 'balance': 575}])
account3 = pd.DataFrame([{'nr': '350', 'balance': 59}])

df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'age': 23, 'name': 'anna', 'account': account1},
                   {'id': 2, 'age':  71, 'name': 'mary', 'account': account2},
                   {'id': 3, 'age':  42, 'name': 'bob', 'account': account3}])

print(df)
```

gives the dataframe:

```
   id  age  name                                          account
0   1   23  anna      nr  balance
0  123       56
1  230       55
1   2   71  mary                      nr  balance
0  456      575
2   3   42   bob                      nr  balance
0  350       59
```

And I would like to get:

```
   id     name  age   account|nr|0     account|balance|0    account|nr|1     account|balance|1
0   1     anna  23    123              56                   230                  55 
1   2     mary  71    456              575
2   3      bob  59    350              59
```

How can I flatten a dataframe inside a dataframe to a single dataframe? This type of structure is called Hierarchical DataFrame?

Comment: your dataframe code is invalid, can you edit/fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I have found.

```
list_accounts = []
for index_j, row_j in df.iterrows():
    account = row_j["account"]
    account = pd.DataFrame(account).stack().to_frame().T
    account.columns = ['%s%s' % (a, '|%s' % b if b else '') for a, b in account.columns]
    list_accounts.append(account)
df = pd.concat([df, pd.concat(list_accounts).reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
df.drop(columns="account", inplace=True)
```